# How to use pagination without reloading main page without pjax

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2, pjax

i'm new at Yii2,
I'm trying to 'call' my gridview after form submit. Okay, I got my gridview. But when I want to change the page , it reloads. My problem that if I want to see next page of gridview, I have to submit form again. All I want is to change pages without refreshing my main page. What should I do? Where i did mistake? Without pjax please, but if it's impossible it's ok. I'll be very happy to see solution to this!!

My model:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Person::find();
 
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 5,
            ],
        ]);
 
        $this->load($params);
 
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
 
 
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->full_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'age', $this->age]);
 
        return $dataProvider;
```

My controller:

```
$model = new Person();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $searchModel = new Person();         
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); 
            return $this->render('persons', [
                'model' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('person_search', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

In **person_search.php** - main form with filters:

```
<div class="search">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'post'
    ]) ?>
<?php
echo $form->field($data, 'name')->textInput();
echo $form->field($data, 'age')->textInput();
?>
</div>
<?= Html::submitButton('search'); ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

In **persons.php** - i render that form for filter and my gridview, here it's:

```
<div class="card">

<?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $model]); ?>

<div class="gridview">
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'name',
                'age',
        ]); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use Ajax?

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: Start by google "getting started with Ajax" and go through a few of the many tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GET instead of POST in your search form, the pagination will work with pajax. 
If you want to use POST method only, you can still use pajax by adding "page" as hidden field in form and changing its value on pagination button click. After that all you have to do is submit the form using pajax. Below is the sample code, please change the attribute names according to your need.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination-btn', function(event) {
  $("#page").val($(this).html());
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
})
```

Source: https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax#pjaxsubmit

This will solve your issue of reloading the page when using pagination links.